# Visual Studio 2010 performance analyze wizard. OpenMP

Tags: visual-c++, openmp

I am writing an c++ application in visual studio 2010. I run my code under performance wizard and it takes nearly 17 seconds. The codes is really suitable to multhreading so I add openmp directives. After that, I run my codes again and it takes also nearly 17 seconds. So, I wonder what that performance wizard does to optimize the code? Does it analyze the code and makes it multithreaded or simple perform compiler optimizations? How that wizard optimize code?

Edit: I enabled compiler options by adding /openmp option. I am using  **#pragma omp parallel for**    directive.I added parallel section codes. it has no bottlenecks, loop iterations do not depend on each other.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = START; i < END; i++) {
    solutionList[i] = new Solution(list[i]->solution, direction, i);        
}
```

Comment: When you add those OpenMP directives, did you also enable OpenMP support in the compiler options? How about setting the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment variable?

Comment: Did you put OpenMP worksharing directives (`omp for` in your case) inside a parallel region? Could you show us some example code that you've applied the OMP directives to? Parallel speedup is highly context specific after all.

Comment: What is the value of `START` and what is the value of `END`? How long does it take to execute the constructor of the `Solution` class? Did you check the `OMP_NUM_THREADS` environment, although by default the number of threads is equal to the number of logical CPUs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance wizard does not optimize your code at all. It measures the execution of your code -- depending on your configuration, by instrumenting the code (making it less efficient but more accurate monitoring). It's a tool you use to decide which areas of your code to examine for optimization -- human optimization of the algorithms, not compiler optimization of the instructions.